# How to avoid Shopping Pricing Rule when applying Catalog Cart Price Rule?

Tags: magento-1.8

I have an ongoing 50% Off Catalog Pricing Rule currently active across my store. A few days back I have also distributed coupon codes on a Radio show with 25% Off. Now i have a situation where customers with these codes are applying the code and receiving a double discount. My $10 product is selling for $3.75 (50% + 25%).

I want a functionality where when the customer applies the coupon code, the code does apply but ONLY on the original price of $10. Thereby selling the product at $7.5. It should overlook the catalog rule. So the customer can choose to either go with the Catalog discount or Coupon discount but not both. Is this possible?

Comment: please help me, i tired to search in google

Comment: no one is there who can help me ?

Comment: can any body give me solution about it Or any alternate option for it ?

Comment: Goto->Catalog Price Rule->Actions->Stop Further Rules Processing->Yes.